# PHP ZF2 translator language switch

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-framework2, translation

Using Zend Framework 2 and Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator, I would like to define the language of the translation dynamically in the same action.
Why ? I need to send email to every customers where the content translation language depends of the language defined in the customer profile. This will be executed by a CRON.

I tried this code for example :

```
/** @var \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator $translator */
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
$translator->setLocale('fr_FR');
AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
/** @var \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer $renderer */
$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer');
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->setTemplate('templatename')->setVariables($data);
var_dump($renderer->render($view));


/** @var \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator $translator */
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
$translator->setLocale('en_EN');
AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
/** @var \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer $renderer */
$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer');
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->setTemplate('templatename')->setVariables($data);
var_dump($renderer->render($view));
```

But both var_dump show the same content in the same language (in this case fr_FR).
Any idea ?

Comment: did you configure module.config.php?

Comment: Yes, all is working fine. I can change the translation based on the URL and language select box, but I can't find the way to reset the translator with another language after it was setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with that is the dependency injection in zf2. in normal cases you define/init your locale in an zf2 event at the beginning of a dispatch event on every request over the `module.php` and `onBootstrap` method.

after the module initiation the `Zend\View\HelperPluginManager` class are loaded through the `ServiceManager` and inject into every `ViewHelper` (`$this->translate` is a ViewHelper too) instance the translator  in the following order.

1. has the `ServiceManager` a `MvcTranslator` instance inject into viewhelper
2. has the `ServiceManager` a `Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface` inject into viewhelper
3. has the `ServiceManager` a `Translator` inject into viewhelper

you change the last instance `Translator` but the viewhelper has a instance of the `MvcTranslator`

use

`$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MvcTranslator');`

and every viewhelper calling internal `getTranslator` `getLocale` return the new locale and use it to translate the given string from `$this->translate('someString');`

Comment: I did not think of that. Seems legit :)

Comment: Yes, you are totally right ! Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this yet with zend framework 2 but i found a tutorial that should help you with what you want to achieve. 
[tutorial](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/zend-framework-2-zendi18ntranslatortranslator-translate-your-web/)

update:

Okay i did not understand correctly. Nonetheless i tried what you are doing and i get the current locale to be en_EN

```
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
$translator->setLocale('fr_FR');
$translator->setLocale('en_EN');
echo  $translator->getLocale();die;
```

so could it be failing to load the English translation and gets the fallback locale(assuming fr_FR) ?

Update 2.

I wanted to try and work something on this since i will soon need it so i tried to create a small test in order to help you with your problem and also learn something about it. But my approach is somewhat different that yours. I hope i understood correctly what you are trying to do.

Controller:

```
    $translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
     $translator->setLocale('fr_FR');
     $locale = $translator->getLocale('fr_FR');
    $textDomain = 'Users\Controller';

    $view = new ViewModel(array(
                   'locale'        => $locale,
                   'textDomain'    => $textDomain,
                    'translator'    => $translator,

                   ));
   return $view;
```

View:

```
<?php echo $translator->translate('Home', $textDomain, $locale); ?>
```

module.config.php:

```
'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
                'text_domain' => __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

From the instructions i was reading it was stated that text_domain should be unique so i am using **NAMESPACE** but i am hard coding that in my controller example above because the test was done on a different namespace so ignore the part just keep in mind that you need it.

So from what i was testing i was able to use the locale i set and translate the word HOME to Accueil. Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply but this doesn't help. As I explained, my translation is working fine, but I need to change the language after the initialisation. And this tutorial doesn't talk about that.

Comment: if I echo  $translator->getLocale(); I get the good locale too, but when I echo $this->translate('dictionnary_term'); in the view, I get the FR translation, not the EN

Comment: I found this solution too, but this is a little dirty because the viewhelper Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate exist and is used everywhere in the application views. So I try to find a way to reinit the translator of the viewhelper Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate . I tried to use the method $renderer->getHelperPluginManager()->injectTranslator(); (renderer is a Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer) but i got no changement.

Comment: sounds to me that you have a new question :)

Comment: oh ? I think I was misunderstood, because that's what I need from the start :)  "I need to send email to every customers where the content translation language depends of the language defined in the customer profile."

Comment: did you make the translation file for that email?

Comment: Yes, I can send this email in every language of the system if the first email is in this language. But for all following emails, they will be in this language too. This concern only the view content.

Comment: if you can add some more code with your email implementation then maybe we can sort something out

Comment: I don't undestand what more code you need. All the concerned part is in my post. I define the local, I render the view and look if the result is translated in the good language.

Comment: Well with 10 lines of code i cannot figure out the hole picture. In any case i applied my logic and i was able to sent a translated email but i cant figure out something better than that.

Comment: You're right, your solution is working, but doesn't accomplish totaly what I need. I really thank you for all the time you spent  to help me